# undefined rest api checkout cart

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

We've multiple websites in Magento (magento2.2.4) and we've got an issue at checkout cart and checkout page.
We have also enable guest checkout.

"/checkout/undefinedrest/buy/V1/guest-carts/.../buy/V1/guest-carts/"

We are getting 404 error at got estimate shipping rate java script issue.

We got bellow error in browser console.

```
/checkout/undefinedrest/buy/V1/guest-carts/873814e048af82699f50cc0055218f6c/estimate-shipping-methods
```

Comment: endpoint should be /rest/V1/guest-carts/873814e048af82699f50cc0055218f6c/estimate-shipping-methods. Have you installed any third party module or done any customizations.

Comment: no, i have using porto them

Comment: I have been traced entire code and found were my rest api are stuck.

IN new "module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-processor" 
 storage.post( => serviceUrl got wrong path 

Its include wrong prefix

Comment: @AnilPrajapati did you found a solution for this? I have the same issue, but my shop is in M2.4