# Magento 2 wrong base url on ajax call on checkout page

Tags: magento2.3, php, api, shipping-methods, checkout-page

I have upgraded the Magento version to 2.3.7. After that, I have a strange issue on the checkout page that when it calls the ajax function the URL is been wrongly generated. Previously it was like

```
<website>/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/AC72N37Vmo3uGMIXEVQfIDt1ubuZLJws/estimate-shipping-methods
```

but after upgrading the Magento version now it's

```
<website>/checkout/undefinedrest/default/V1/guest-carts/AC72N37Vmo3uGMIXEVQfIDt1ubuZLJws/estimate-shipping-methods
```

Not sure from where this undefined gets added within the URL ??

Research Notes: -

The secure & unsecure base URL is correctly set up. I checked it again

Also, I navigated to the file from where this ajax call is generated, the file is

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js
```

[image]

Here is the storage. post is from the ajax call is generated and it has
service URL & payload as arguments.

in get Rates function - if we console.log "`serviceUrl`" then it shows the below URL

```
rest/default/V1/guest-carts/FsS4QvllSq1vpuxZuC8ycQa0VRMOcQCy/estimate-shipping-methods
```

which seem to be correct, storage.post() function takes this as an argument and ajax request is called which then gets into the .fail() function

so what I think is that the problem is where the front part of the URL gets added to it for making the ajax call that is
http://sitename.local/checkout/undefined ---> and here somehow the undefined gets added which breaks the whole URL

The same issue is encountered by other users also but no solution is available yet.

[undefined rest api checkout cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256273/undefined-rest-api-checkout-cart)

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento2-Wrong-base-url-on-ajax-call/td-p/435435

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways.

1. Take the entire `checkout` module from the same fresh magento version.
2. Try to do the magento upgrade again with composer.

So if any mistake remain into upgrade can be resolve.